# External script files not loaded in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am just starting in meteor. I have create 4 folders, client, server , public and both. I have put some js files that my app depends upon in the public folder. But when I load my app and check the network tab, those files are not being included.
This is the structure of the public folder.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer. I had to keep those files in lib folder.